# How to use SAS Token in Azure File Copy Pipeline Task?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-task, azure-file-copy

I am trying to copy ADF ARM templates to a storage account using the Azure File Copy Task in my Azure release pipeline. Since the storage account has firewall and networking set up, I want to use the SAS token to allow the Pipeline agent to copy the files to the storage account.

However, I am not able to find any documentation as to how to pass the SAS token as the optional argument(or at another place).
The task version is 2*.
How do I use the SAS token for copying the files?

[image: Pipeline Task - File Copy]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the file copy task version to 4*. ; and then I was able to add
`--sas-token=$(sasToken)` into the Optional Arguments and it worked for me.